# How can I prove that $x^5+ax^4+bx^3+c=0$ has at least 2 complex roots?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Suppose $c\neq 0$, how can I prove that $x^5+ax^4+bx^3+c=0$ has at least 2 complex roots?

I tried Lagrange Mean Value Theorem, but it seemed not work.

Comment: What are a, b and c? You need to start there.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio  What I have known is that $c/neq 0$.

Comment: But where do they live? If they are real numbers, the question is trivial. Is at least one of them not real?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $c \ne 0,\;$all the roots are nonzero, and so are their reciprocals.

Since the equation for the roots is
$$x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3 + c = 0$$
the equation for the reciprocals of the roots is
$$cx^5 + bx^2 + ax + 1 = 0$$
hence, letting $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5\;$denote the reciprocals of the roots, Vieta's formulas yield
\begin{align*}
e_1 &= \sum_{i=1}^5\,w_i = 0\\[4pt]
e_2 &= \sum_{1\le i < j \le 5}\!\!\!w_iw_j = 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which gives
$$\sum_{i=1}^5\;w_i^2 = e_1^2-2e_2 = 0$$

It follows that $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5\;$cannot all be real.

Assuming the coefficients are real, at least two of $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5\;$must be non-real.

Hence the same is true for the original roots.